# Rename the develop branch with Gitflow into dev

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

We are used to have a development branch called dev, in Gitflow toolset it is called develop.

https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh

Is there a way to tell Gitflow that we want to use a branch called **dev**?

Thanks

Comment: You want to renaming a already created `feature/develop` branch to `feature/dev`?

Comment: The branch is already called dev, so I juste needed "git config gitflow.branch.develop dev", thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Rename the branch in Git

   ```
   git branch -m develop dev
   ```
2. Update gitflow config

   ```
   git config gitflow.branch.develop dev
   ```